# Understanding simple stream transforms in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working through some Learnyounode/nodeschool examples and am hoping to get a better understanding of stream transforms. I've created a simple http server in node using `http.createServer()`. My hope is to be able to understand streams well enough first without having to lean on helper libraries like `through` or `through2`. I'd love to it more 'natively-to-node' if at all possible and gain a better understanding of the streaming notion in node that way.

Given a POST request (which is guaranteed in this learning case), I'm wanting to transform the characters in the body of the request to uppercase characters using `.toUpperCase()`. I'm familiar enough with JS to find that part easy, but my confusion stems mainly from why the stream I am `.pipe()`-ing to the `response` isn't transformed.

I'm able to `log()` out the transformed characters, but for some reason I'm not seeing they don't get returned as actually-transformed characters. I know that `.toUpperCase()` doesn't affect the actual string itself, but I am returning that value, so it that doesn't seem to be where my confusion lies (but please help me clarify if I'm wrong about that). Thanks everyone!

**Sample input on POST**:

bob

Joe

larry

**Expected output**:

BOB

JOE

LARRY

**Actual output:**

bob

Joe

larry

**My simple server**:

```
var http = require('http')
var port = process.argv[2]

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.method != 'POST') {
    console.log('You have failed to comply with our stringent demands');
    return false
   }
  req.on('data', function(chunk) {
     return chunk.toString().toUpperCase()
  }).pipe(res);
})

server.listen(port)
```

**EDIT** *What I learned:*
Per the accepted answer below, not all streams in node support transforms on their own. When you need to perform a transform on a readableStream (or other similar type), create a stream.transform() and pipe that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Readable streams don't on their own support transforms.

You'll want to create a [`stream.Transform`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform) and define its [`_transform()`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_transform_transform_chunk_encoding_callback), then chain it between `req` and `res` with another [`.pipe()`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options):

```
var stream = require('stream');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  // ...

  var uppercase = new stream.Transform();
  uppercase._transform = function (data, enc, cb) {
    cb(null, data.toString().toUpperCase());  
  };

  req.pipe(uppercase).pipe(res);
})
```

Comment: Ahh. That makes sense. 1 follow-up question: I've read that the `streams` module is unstable (I know it has a 2 stability index) and people suggest other libs in it's place. Is it generally good to trust that advice or is it more case-by-case and `streams` can be somewhat relied upon?

Comment: and is this generally true for all stream types in Node? are transforms separated to their own area of concern?